# Не получается русифицировать ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

есть ubuntu в докере, выполнил команды

```
apt-get install language-pack-ru language-pack-ru-base language-pack-gnome-ru language-pack-gnome-ru-base
```

в  `/etc/default/locale`
прописал
`LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8`

Но в консоли все также, вместо русский символов либо знаки вопроса либо набор цифр.
Команда locale выдает такой результат

```
LANG=                                                                                                                                                                                                       
LANGUAGE=                                                                                                                                                                                                   
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                            
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                          
LC_TIME="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                             
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                          
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                         
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                         
LC_PAPER="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                            
LC_NAME="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                             
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                          
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                        
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                      
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"                                                                                                                                                                                   
LC_ALL=
```

что не так делаю?
`dpkg-reconfigure locales` тоже делал

Comment: Простите за возможно глупый вопрос, но зачем русифицировать ubuntu **в докере**?

Comment: @andreymal программа на java там стоит, которая работает с кириллицей, и вместо кириллицы везде знаки вопроса

Comment: Для решения проблем с кодировками нужно не русифицировать, а просто правильную кодировку установить в нужном месте. Лучше бы написали вопрос про эту самую программу на java

Comment: @andreymal может и так, но все равно это пол проблемы, мне нужно отвечать программе в консоль русскими словами) так что в любом случае, хочу перевести

Comment: Для набора русского текста в консоли тоже ничего не нужно русифицировать, а опять же нужно просто правильную кодировку поставить

Comment: Возможно что-нибудь такое https://askubuntu.com/q/581458

Comment: наверно, пора заводить отдельную причину закрытия «[проблема молотка и микроскопа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)».

Comment: всё, что вы написали в ворпосе, никакого отношения к действительной проблеме, о которой вы упомянули лишь в комментариях, не имеет. наверно, лучше будет, если вы удалите данный вопрос, и создадите новый, в котором и изложите действительную проблему с вашей программой.